# Removing excess padding on primefaces button

Tags: primefaces

I am having a bit of a problem styling the commandbutton of the primefaces 3 application.

My common CSS has this style

```
body {
    font-size: small;
}
```

and my primefaces button has this

```
<p:commandButton value="Search" ajax="false"  style="padding:0px;"/>
```

I wanted to remove some padding on the button itself so I have set its style as above.

But nothing is happening?

Is there a way to remove the excess padding on command button?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The css class that is responsible for the padding is `.ui-button-text`. You can verify it with Firebug or some other tool.

You could override this default style with the following code snippet. Put it in the header section of your page:

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .ui-button-text {
         padding: 0px !important;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but in my case this was not working.

Alternative way is using `display:none;` as shown below.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-button-text {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```